# Is it possible to get the window url of a 3rd party Electron-based application using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bash, electron, chromium

I am looking into ways of getting the URL of a 3rd party electron application (e.g. Slack) using bash or any other executable. Does not matter which platform. I can't seem to find a way of getting this URL, except modifying files of the application before running.

Comment: Not sure to understand, but you can try to find it by opening the app devtools (look for the keyboard shortcut, it's cmd+alt+i on macOS for example).

Comment: This is a manual way of getting the url. I am looking for a way to automate it.